# xbox360 controller will not show up as dev/input/js0

Tags: ubuntu-studio, input-devices, xbox-360

I have a wired xbox360 controller. I want to use it in Ubuntu Studio (kde) 22.04.2 LTS with python3. The same controller works perfectly under Bodhi Linux 22.04.

However, in Ubuntu Studio no folder `/dev/input/jsX` is created when I plug in the controller.

`lsusb` says:

```
Bus 003 Device 037: ID 057e:2009 Nintendo Co., Ltd Switch Pro Controller
```

For another gamepad (which works on a Nintento Switch):

```
Bus 003 Device 039: ID 0f0d:00c1 Hori Co., Ltd HORIPAD for Nintendo Switch
```

it's all the same.

I don't know what to do here? Any hints?

Best regards
Peter

Comment: If your Ubuntu 22.04 system still reports as 22.04.2, then I'll suggest applying security fixes asap as you're behind. This page (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/08/11/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-released/) shows the ISO release of 22.04.3, however installed systems upgraded to 22.04.3 in the week before the ISO release. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS being a LTS has kernel stack choices; thus I'd firstly explore that (ie. Ubuntu (inc. *flavor*) install media sets the GA/HWE or OEM kernel stack default; I don't know what Bodhi uses or defaults to)  ... ie. difference may only be kernel stack default

Comment: Thank for the hints. I updated, now its 22.04.3 :-)

Comment: I used uname to see my kernel-versions. On Ubuntu Studio it is Linux 6.2.0-1009-lowlatency x86_64, on Bodhi it is Linux 5.4.0-131-generic x86_64. Don't know yet, what to do with this.

Comment: Your Bodhi Linux isn't using a 22.04 kernel, but a kernel from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, as the GA kernel stack of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS was 5.15. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using the HWE kernel stack used 5.4, and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS used the 5.4 kernel, thus the software sin your Bodhi is much much older than your Ubuntu system being a clue; ie. your Bodhi is based on 20.04 or older. I'd firstly try not using the *low latency* kernel (ie. select standard at grub during boot) as *low latency* won't work with all hardware as Ubuntu Studio documentation says (*they wrote that for a reason; it was discovered in QA!*)